# swift Firebase stop signup process

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to stop the signup process if the username exists. I don't want to create Email\Password (Authentication) and other info if the username exists

database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "(auth != null)",
        ".indexOn": ["username"],
      "$uid": {


            "$username":{
          ".write": "(auth != null) && !data.exists() || newData.exists()"

          }



      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added `!data.exists()` in .write , but still it duplicate usernames.
And then I added `".validate"` to make username atleast 3 characters, to see if the signup process gonna fail if its longer, but it created email\password and other stuff but didn't wrote any data in database root\users\

After registered new user with email\password I got this error, Which means username couldn't be more than 3 characters. **How to stop the signup process and show alert message at this situation?**

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] setValue: or removeValue: at /users/jt94ARqOoodtU3kYp3W1MtlUZ4m1 failed: permission_denied

Please help me if you could fix the problem.

Comment: At your case you are adding the user to authentication part then testing inverse the steps, you have to first check the data at the client side then make the authentication.

Comment: @OussemaAroua Can you answer and explain? I have no idea im just new with firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplified rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".write": "(auth != null)",
     "users": {
        "$uid": {
           "username": {
                     ".write": "auth != null  && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists())",
```

So you first grant any authenticated user write access on the root of the data and subsequently say that a user can only write if there is not data a the current location.

That won't work: once you grant permissions at a certain level, you cannot take that permission away on a lower level.

The Firebase documentation describes this as [Read and Write rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

Comment: So is there anyway to stop registering users if there exists username? i'm new with firebase, please edit your answer with some solutions.

Comment: Sure. Just remove the top-level `.write` rule, to prevent giving users write permission that you don't want.

Comment: I've removed that before i ask my question but still i'm getting "permission_denied" also if username exists or not and wont write anything in database and still creating Authentication which is email\password. how to stop creating if there's exists username, That's so confused. (I've edited my rules)

Comment: It's hard to say what precisely triggers that now. Please update your question to include the [minimum code (with hardcoded values) that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).